# UISearchController in navigation bar could not hide properly on iOS 11

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller, abcustomuinavcontroller

I want to hide navigation bar after a tap

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

The navigationBar hides properly after a tap 
[image: hide Navigation Bar]

But after adding a searchController (code below)

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

My view (cyan color) could not extend correctly

[image: not properly]

And I also tried rotated it. The search bar appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(barHideAction(_:)))
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
}

@objc func barHideAction(_ guesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    updateFrame()
}

func updateFrame() {
    if let nc = navigationController {
        let isHidden = nc.isNavigationBarHidden
        searchController.searchBar.superview?.isHidden = isHidden

        if isHidden {
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = -64 // fixed by a magic num
        }
        else {
            self.additionalSafeAreaInsets.top = 0
        }
    }
}
```

[example code](https://github.com/iosexample/TestSearchController)